# Properties info in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

How do I see changing properties while I drag the item with my mouse in Android Studio design as follows:

[image]

I tried checking "Show quick doc on mouse move" but I still can't see it as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click on a certain view/widget in the Component Tree panel, and then click the "View all properties" button in the Properties panel as follows:

[image]

... Or, of course you could resort to XML instead for coding the properties/attributes under the "Text" tab.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. What I am asking, I need to see the changing properties when I move the item (like it is in first picture)